# iam trying to make slash command reply using discord js with attachment images without using embed but cant seems to make it right

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

I want to make it so my bot can reply to the slash command with images. my plan here is to use MessageAttachment to get the images URL and call it using await interaction.
This is the error I am getting from logs

iam using dicord js v13

```
2021-09-24T03:27:36.954175+00:00 app[service.1]:     at Object.execute (/app/commands/cook.js:13:27)
2021-09-24T03:27:36.954175+00:00 app[service.1]:     at Client.<anonymous> (/app/index.js:28:17)
2021-09-24T03:27:36.954176+00:00 app[service.1]:     at Client.emit (node:events:394:28)
2021-09-24T03:27:36.954177+00:00 app[service.1]:     at InteractionCreateAction.handle (/app/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/actions/InteractionCreate.js:66:12)
2021-09-24T03:27:36.954178+00:00 app[service.1]:     at Object.module.exports [as INTERACTION_CREATE] (/app/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/handlers/INTERACTION_CREATE.js:4:36)
2021-09-24T03:27:36.954178+00:00 app[service.1]:     at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (/app/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketManager.js:345:31)
2021-09-24T03:27:36.954179+00:00 app[service.1]:     at WebSocketShard.onPacket (/app/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketShard.js:443:22)
2021-09-24T03:27:36.954179+00:00 app[service.1]:     at WebSocketShard.onMessage (/app/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketShard.js:300:10)
2021-09-24T03:27:36.954180+00:00 app[service.1]:     at WebSocket.onMessage (/app/node_modules/ws/lib/event-target.js:132:16)
2021-09-24T03:27:36.954180+00:00 app[service.1]:     at WebSocket.emit (node:events:394:28)
```

Here is my code

```
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require('@discordjs/builders');
const { Message, MessageAttachment } = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName('cook')
        .setDescription('aaa'),
    async execute(interaction) {
        const imagecook = new MessageAttachment('https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/587243063932354560/861940902359728128/gurucooking_long.png');
        await interaction.replay({attachment: [imagecook]});
```

Comment: Your error is not complete, rather from midst of a stack trace, could you share the error from the top?

Answer (score 1):

I think you just misspelled `replay` because it should be `interaction.reply()`